# I want to Add My Product Image to Admin Order Email in Woocommerece

Tags: images, plugins, email, order

I want to Add my product image (product which is ordered) in a thumbnail form to recognize the product easily by admin, in Admin Order Email.

Comment: Please show us code how you send email. Because we are not getting any idea what you are doing and where you are wrong in code.

Comment: Now that we know what it is you *want* - what is your question? Also, be so kind as to provide some code context and/or research effort.

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually i am not so familiar with codes, so the simple thing i need is to have some code added to the woocommerce admin mail which we get when somebody orders on our shopping site, the code will add my product thumbnail to the mail which consist only Product name, quantity, price and total cost, as my some product name are approx same but consist different things

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) This is not a place to ask for code snippets. It is a place to get help with your own code.

Answer (score 3):

The default admin email can be found in `woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php`

the order items table is called in line 28, with a function called `email_order_items_table`. This function also takes an argument for including the thumbnail (see the `class-wc-order.php`, line 1052). if you *copy the email templates to your theme folder*, you can edit the `admin-new-order.php` file and use the following on line 28:

```
    <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( false, true, false, true ); ?>
```

Comment: Please help me in one thing more, in case i need to resize the thumbnail, as its really small how could i update the code. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: it's in the same argument, check `class-wc-order.php`, line 1052

Comment: Although this question is old, I'd like to suggest an easier solution. With WP HTML Mail (http://wphtmlmail.com) thumbnails and many more details of WooCommerce emails can be customized without a single line of code.